# Print IE page from script on Windows Server 2012

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2012-r2

I have this VBScript running on a Server 2008 R2 machine and it runs fine, printing as it should to the default printer.

I have moved the script to a Server 2012 R2 machine, and it won't print.

```
Dim rs
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim strsql
strsql="select orders_htmlfiles.id, replace(name,'\','/') as newname from orders_htmlfiles left join orders on orders_htmlfiles.ordernumber=orders.ordernumber "
strsql= strsql & " where printed=0 "
rs.open strsql, adoConProdRead

Dim IE
Dim URL
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Do while not rs.eof
  If fso.FileExists(rs("newname")) Then
    URL="file:///"+rs("newname")
    IE.Visible = false
    IE.Navigate URL
    While IE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
    Wend
    IE.ExecWB 6, 2
    WScript.Sleep 1000

    strsqlupdate="Update orders_htmlfiles set printed=1, printdatetime='" & now & "' where id=" & rs("id")
    Set objExec = adoConProdRead.Execute(strsqlupdate)

    WScript.Sleep 10000
  Else
    'msgbox "file not found"
  End if
  rs.movenext
Loop
rs.close
Set rs=Nothing

IE.Quit
```

Comment: Same IE version? IE enhanced security configuration configured the same way?

Comment: Here is an update.  The script actually works fine when I run the VBS file, it doesn't however print with I run the scheduled task that I have created.

Comment: And the scheduled task runs under the same account?

Comment: Correct, as the admin on the machine.

Comment: UAC enabled? Did you set "run with highest privileges"?

Comment: Just tried to disable UAC, no difference, Also recreated task.

Comment: Just to cross-check: Confirm that your script can actually see a proper default printer by [adding a few lines of WMI code](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/11/17/hey-scripting-guy-is-there-any-way-to-determine-the-default-printer-on-a-computer.aspx) to it and letting it write the result to a file as proof.